# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

working on a project here. I am using Nextjs and Typescript. I have tabs, in one tab I am getting a lot of objects passed through, I made a reduce function to sort and push everything in its proper category. I came across this problem

> Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.

Specifically under every `title` (marked with comments here) inside of the reduce function.

interface:

```
export interface ITimelineItem {
  title?: string
  subtitle?: string
  date?: string
  reference?: string
  description?: string
  skillSet?: string
  reverse?: boolean
  startYear?: string
  endYear?: string
}

interface ITimeline {
  items?: ITimelineItem[]
}

const TimeLine: React.FC<ITimeline> = ({ items = [] }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const cat = items.reduce((item, { skillSet, title }) => {
    if (!item[title!]) item[title] = []
    //        ^^^^^        ^^^^^
    item[title].push(skillSet)
    //   ^^^^^

    return item
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: Your example is full of syntax errors. Please provide a reproducible one. Also, please consider formatting. Try to use [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Please... Even if we try fix the compiler error, the given code is incomplete and has logical errors. Please provide the complete function, or at least take out the unnecessary bits.

Answer (score 1):

Since in `ITimelineItem` `title` is marked as optional, it can be `undefined`, which cannot be used to index objects. To fix it, add a check for `title` before using it as index.

```
if (title !== undefined && !item[title]) item[title] = []
```

You can also use non-null assertion operator here, but the code will break if the `title` is actually `undefined` and it basically defeats the purpose of TS here.

```
if (!item[title!]) item[title] = []
```